# Confusion about solution to ideals question involving intersections

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have the following question here.

> Let $a,b \in\mathbb{Z} \backslash \{0\}$, and let $I=(a\mathbb{Z})\cap(b\mathbb{Z})$.

> a) Show that $I$ is a non-zero ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

> b) Show that $I=m\mathbb{Z}$, where $m$ is the least positive element of $I$.

> c) Show that $m$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$, and that every common multiple of $a$ and $b$ is a multiple of $m$.

I'm very confused about the way my professor wrote the solution.

a) $I$ is non-empty because it contains $ab$, and this shows simultaneously that it contains a non-zero element. Next, if $x,y \in I$, then on the one
hand, $x$ and $y$ are both multiples of $a$, so their difference $x-y$ is as well, showing that $x-y \in a\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, the same argument shows that $x-y$ is in $b\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $x-y \in I$. Finally, let $x \in I$ and $y \in Z$. Then $x$ is a multiple of $a$, so the same is true of $yx$, showing that $yx \in aZ$. Similarly, $yx \in bZ$, so $yx \in I$.

**I understand this now with a concrete example.**

b) Because $m \in I$ and $I$ is closed under both addition and subtraction,$m\mathbb{Z} \subseteq I$. Conversely, let $l \in I$, and write $l = qm + r$ with $q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $0 \leq r < m$. Then $r = l - qm \in I$ because $I$ is an ideal, so by the minimality of $m$, $r$ must be zero. Thus, $l = qm \in m\mathbb{Z}$.

**Where is the  $l = qm + r$ coming from and why?**

c) By definition, $m$ is in $I = (a\mathbb{Z}) \cup (b\mathbb{Z})$, so $m$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. Further, if $l$ is any common multiple of $a$ and $b$, then $l \in a\mathbb{Z}$ and $l \in b\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., $l \in (a\mathbb{Z}) \cap (b\mathbb{Z}) = I = m\mathbb{Z}$, so $l$ is a multiple of $m$.

**I think I get what this is saying? Basically, $m$ is a multiple of $a$ and $b$ and because $l$ is also a multiple of $m$, it must also be a multiple of of $m$, is that right?**

**Can someone also explain, notationally, what does $I=(a\mathbb{Z})\cap(b\mathbb{Z})$ mean?**

EDIT: Wrote $l \in (a\mathbb{Z}) \cap (b\mathbb{Z}) = I = m\mathbb{Z}$ which is correct instead of $l \in (a\mathbb{Z}) \cup (b\mathbb{Z}) = I = m\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: For part (c), i believe you mean $(a\mathbb{Z})\cap(b\mathbb{Z})$ rather than $(a\mathbb{Z})\cup(b\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: Yes I just edited now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is the $l=qm+r$ coming from and why?

This comes from the division algorithm. Indeed, $l$ can be uniquely written as $$l=qm+r$$
with $q,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ and such that $0\leq r<m$. Why do we do this? The point is that we want to prove that any $l\in I$ is a multiple of $m$. Hence if for some reason $r=0$, we accomplished that goal.

> Can someone also explain, notationally, what does $I=(a\mathbb{Z})\cap(b\mathbb{Z})$ mean?

By definition $(k\mathbb{Z})=\{kz\mid z\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, this is the set of all integer multiples of $k$. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: I got almost all of it but I am still not sure why I should consider $r=0$. How can we just "randomly" do that?

Comment: It's not random. We find that $l=qm+r$ and thus $r=l-qm$. Note that $qm\in I$ as $m\in I$ and $I$ is an ideal. Furthermore, $l\in I$ as well. As ideals are closed under sums, $r=l-qm\in I$. This means that $r$ belongs to $I$ and $r$ is a positive number. By definition, $m$ was the smallest non-zero positive number of $I$ but $r$ is a smaller such number. The only way this can hold, is if $r$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: Ahh perfect. That clicked. Thanks a lot!